# How to count unique values in rows with PHPActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, unique, phpactiverecord

For example, I have table:

```
id | number
-----------
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 2
6  | 3
```

i need to count unique `number`s (1, 2 and 3), that is 3

i have working SQL code:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `number`) AS `total` FROM `some_table`
```

but i don't know how better to do this with PHPActiveRecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `count()` function in phpAR, but you can't make it work with DISTINCT. So, I think the easiest is:

```
$total = SomeModel::first(['select' => 'COUNT(DISTINCT `number`) AS `total`'])->total;
```